# Crackle, pop and distorsion when recording in Cubase

Tags: cubase

What can I do about crackle and pop that comes when I do recording in Cubase? When I play the song it is clean but when I try and record it to an audio track is is distorted and crackeled.

Comment: I think this question would be far better addressed to Steinberg. Best guess is you have the buffer too short, but it would take 20 questions to try work through a step-by-step diagnosis, which is not the purpose of Stack Exchange. See [Why we're not customer support for \[your favourite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: @Tetsujin I doubled the buffer and now it sounds good. Thanks!